# Order list by property in nested list

Tags: c#, list, sorting, nested-lists

I have the following structures in c#:

```
public class Circus {
    int Id;
    public List<Performers> Performers = new List<Performers>();
}

public class Performer {
    int Id;
    public List<Talents> Talents = new List<Talents>();
}

public class Talent {
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int skill;
}
```

How would I order Performers by skill (where Talent.Id == 1)? That is to say, I need to order a List by a property of it's child List. I've tried various attempts and searches but nothing as of yet will order the list in this way. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Show one of your attempts that did not work.  It is better to show broken code than no code.

Comment: Also... what should the sorting behavior be if Talents is null, empty, or contains no Talent with the ID of 1?

Comment: @Eric J: sorry. I had been typing/deleting code for about the past hour. I could have tried to recall some of my attempts that I thought were close I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ solution:

```
var ordered = source.OrderBy(p => p.Talents.First(t => t.Id == 1).Skill).ToList();
```

Comment: This will fail if Talents is null.  I think it will also fail if there is no Talent with an Id of 1.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see what I was missing now in all my attempts. It was the .Skill portion. Although I had Skill included, I did not have it in the correct spot. Thank you again.

Comment: @Eric J: There is a null check before this line is run, and there is not a hardcoded id value in the code, this was just for example purposes.